# Proving that the usual metric (squareroot of squares) has the triangle inequality - BUT the short way (Minkowski's inequality)

Tags: real-analysis

I have proved Minkowski's inquality, this means I know that:

For $x_i,y_i\ge0$ and $p\ge1$ that:
$$\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i+y_i)^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}\le\left(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}+\left(\sum^n_{i=1}y_i^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$

I want to prove:
$$\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\le\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-z_i)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(z_i-y_i)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Let $a_i=x_i-z_i$ and $b_i=z_i-y_i$ then:

$$\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(a_i+b_i)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\le\left(\sum^n_{i=1}a_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\sum^n_{i=1}b_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Which is basically Minkowski's inequality (for $p=2$) except that I have no guarantee that $x_i\ge0$ and the same for $y$

So I want to pick an $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ say such that $(\alpha_i+\beta_i)^2=(a_i+b_i)^2$ and that $a_i^2=\alpha_i^2$ and the same for $\beta$ and $b$.

The only real choice is $\alpha_i=|a_i|$ and the same for $\beta$ and $b$ but I'm not confident this works.

By trying to avoid proving it the long way I have taken quiet a bit of time. I want to know if this is hopeless or if I simply missed it, can I prove this using Minkowski's inequality?

### Addendum

My thinking is $(|x+y|)^2=(x+y)^2$ - now I've managed to write down what I mean "but the taking square part makes it positive, thus a sum of positive terms" I might be able to do it, I'll post an answer if I do.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!
Note that for $x\ge0$ to have $\sqrt{x+k}\ge\sqrt{x}\implies x+k\ge x \implies k\ge0$ - (how to prove sqrt is increasing?)

Anyway!

Consider $(x+y)^2=|x+y|^2$ (not sure how to prove, but I know)

Then $\sum(x+y)^2=\sum|x+y|^2\le\sum(|x|+|y|)^2$

For $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ we have $|a+b|+k=|a|+|b|$ for some $k\ge0$

Then $$\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(a_i+b_i)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}=
\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(|a_i+b_i|)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}=
\left(k+\sum^n_{i=1}(|a_i|+|b_i|)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Which is (by the increasing-ness of squareroot)
$$\le\left(\sum^n_{i=1}(|a_i|+|b_i|)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\le\left(\sum^n_{i=1}|a_i|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\sum^n_{i=1}|b_i|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$
By Holder's inequ.
But $|a_i|^2=a_i^2$, so

$$=\left(\sum^n_{i=1}a_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\left(\sum^n_{i=1}b_i^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$